# Per class weighted loss for multiclass-multilabel classification in ML.net

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

I want to classify several classes, lets say A, B,C and D but the dataset is unbalanced (class A can have 60% of cases). For that reason, multiclass classification algorithms in ML.NET tend to predict A.

This unbalanced situation is common in the population of my problem: A is more frequent than the others, B uses to more frequent than C and C uses to be more frequent than D. For now, I'm not interested in sampling up/down the dataset or increase size of the dataset to solve this problem (unless there are not other options).

In the context of my problem predict successfully B is more valuable than predict A, predict C is more valuable than B and predict D is more valuable than C. So I'm interested in give more weight to classes B, C and D in order to tell the algorithm to take more risks and try to predict other classes.

But I cannot find the way to do it in ML.Net. I know that it can be done with loss functions, but there are not much information about it and I could not find any example in ML.net. I tried to implement custom loss function (class CustomLoss : ISupportSdcaClassificationLoss, ISupportSdcaLoss, IScalarLoss, ILossFunction<float, float>, IClassificationLoss) and I tried to inject it to (MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaNonCalibrated) but no success because the ground truth is always 1 (it does not represent the truth class so I cannot know which class I'm calculating the loss)

Any ideas to solve that with ML.net? If not, Are there some good alternatives to ML.net in C# to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try it Tensorflow.NET as a good alternative https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET